# how to show thumbimage in gridview from sdcard

Tags: android

iam using following code it is not displaying thumb image in gridview but displaying in emulator pls suggest me how to show thumb image in gridview from sdcard

```
String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};
        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID+" DESC";

        // Create the cursor pointing to the SDCard
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection, // Which columns to return
                null,       // Return all rows
                null,       
                orderBy); 

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
        int size = cursor.getCount();
        // If size is 0, there are no images on the SD Card.
        if (size == 0) {
            //No Images available, post some message to the user
        }
        int imageID = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            cursor.moveToPosition(i);
            imageID = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
            uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + imageID);
            try {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 86, 96, true);
                    bitmap.recycle();
                    if (newBitmap != null) {
                        publishProgress(new LoadedImage(newBitmap));
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
```

Comment: check you may get bitmap is null because it some device no thumbnail is generated instead you can use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.html#getThumbnail(android.content.ContentResolver, long, int, android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options) getThumbnail

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it will work

```
package com.video;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;


public class StartActivity extends Activity {
    //set constants for MediaStore to query, and show videos
    private final static Uri MEDIA_EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    private final static String _ID = MediaStore.Video.Media._ID;
    private final static String MEDIA_DATA = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA;
    //flag for which one is used for images selection
    private GridView _gallery; 
    private Cursor _cursor;
    private int _columnIndex;
    private int[] _videosId;
    private Uri _contentUri;


    protected Context _context;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        _context = getApplicationContext();
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //set GridView for gallery
        _gallery = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.videoGrdVw);
        //set default as external/sdcard uri
        _contentUri = MEDIA_EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        //initialize the videos uri 
        //showToast(_contentUri.getPath());
        initVideosId();
        //set gallery adapter
        setGalleryAdapter();
    }
    private void setGalleryAdapter() {
        _gallery.setAdapter(new VideoGalleryAdapter(_context));
        _gallery.setOnItemClickListener(_itemClickLis);

    }
    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener _itemClickLis = new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) 
        {
            // Now we want to actually get the data location of the file
            String [] proj={MEDIA_DATA};
            // We request our cursor again
            _cursor = managedQuery(_contentUri,
                    proj, // Which columns to return
                    null,       // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)
                    null,       // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
                    null); // Order-by clause (ascending by name)
            // We want to get the column index for the data uri
            int count = _cursor.getCount();
            //
            _cursor.moveToFirst();
            //
            _columnIndex = _cursor.getColumnIndex(MEDIA_DATA);
            // Lets move to the selected item in the cursor
            _cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            // And here we get the filename
            String filename = _cursor.getString(_columnIndex);
            //*********** You can do anything when you know the file path :-)
            showToast(filename);
            //
        }
    };
    private void initVideosId() {
        try
        {
            //Here we set up a string array of the thumbnail ID column we want to get back
            String [] proj={_ID};
            // Now we create the cursor pointing to the external thumbnail store
            _cursor = managedQuery(_contentUri,
                    proj, // Which columns to return
                    null,       // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)
                    null,       // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
                    null); // Order-by clause (ascending by name)
            int count= _cursor.getCount();
            // We now get the column index of the thumbnail id
            _columnIndex = _cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID);
            //initialize 
            _videosId = new int[count];
            //move position to first element
            _cursor.moveToFirst();          
            for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
            {           
                int id = _cursor.getInt(_columnIndex);
                //
                _videosId[i]= id;
                //
                _cursor.moveToNext();
                //
            }
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            showToast(ex.getMessage().toString());          
        }

    }
    protected void showToast(String msg)
    {
        Toast.makeText(_context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    //
    private class VideoGalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        public VideoGalleryAdapter(Context c) 
        {
            _context = c;
        }
        public int getCount() 
        {
            return _videosId.length;
        }
        public Object getItem(int position) 
        {
            return position;
        }
        public long getItemId(int position) 
        {
            return position;
        }
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            ImageView imgVw= new ImageView(_context);;
            try
            {
                if(convertView!=null)
                {
                    imgVw= (ImageView) convertView;
                }
                imgVw.setImageBitmap(getImage(_videosId[position]));
                imgVw.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(96, 96));
                imgVw.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                System.out.println("StartActivity:getView()-135: ex " + ex.getClass() +", "+ ex.getMessage());
            }
            return imgVw;
        }

        // Create the thumbnail on the fly
        private Bitmap getImage(int id) {
            Bitmap thumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                    getContentResolver(),
                    id, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
            return thumb;
        }

    }


}
```